# Grammatical usage of "で" in the sample sentence: 「～～で正解だと思います。」

Tags: grammar, particle-で

> "Do you mean the red haired boy?"
> は、「赤毛の男の子のことですか？」**で**正解だと思います。

So this is an explanation I got from a Japanese person.

And I wanna understand what does exactly "で" mean here. Why is it not "が" because it is a positive sentence and all.

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/59906/9831　Also related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/95612/9831

Answer (score 1):

The で is broadly *with, by* as usual. Slightly more precisely, it is 基準(#6 [here](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E3%81%A7/#je-50708)), perhaps 材料(#3) is relevant too.

A typical usage is

- 私はこれでいいです *I'm okay with this*

meaning you are happy with what you have at hand.

Using が sounds excluding other possibilities of translations (as *This **is** the correct one*). Using で makes it sound like *This is **a** correct translation*.

---

Some other similar usage

- リンゴはひとつ**で**十分です One apple is enough
- コップはみっつ**で**足ります Three cups will be enough